# while building C application with .lib file Code blocks Error

Tags: c, codeblocks, .lib

-------------- Build: Debug in test2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g -Ibin -I"C:\Users\Tigris\Desktop\c codes\test2\" -c "C:\Users\Tigris\Desktop\c codes\test2\main.c" -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-gcc.exe: error: codes\test2\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o: No such file or directory
mingw32-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files

Comment: it seems unlikely that this parameter: -Ibin is correct, as (normally) a bin directory contains libraries and executables, not header files.

Comment: the file path references, such as: obj\Debug\main.o are giving an absolute path. what you probably want is: .\obj\Debug\main.o so you get a relative path based on the current directory.